# Returning largest product of longest subsequence between min and max

Tags: python, comparative-review

This function returns the largest product of all elements of a list between the leftmost and rightmost min and max elements. Is there more readable and maybe compact way to rewrite the `elif` chain in this code:

```
from operator import mul
from functools import reduce

prod = lambda iterable: reduce(mul, iterable, 1)

def prod_between_min_and_max(arr):
    l_min, r_max = arr.index(min(arr)), len(arr)-1 - arr[::-1].index(max(arr))
    l_max, r_min = arr.index(max(arr)), len(arr)-1 - arr[::-1].index(min(arr))
    if len(range(l_min, r_max+1)) > len(range(l_max, r_min+1)):
        sl = slice(l_min, r_max+1)
    elif len(range(l_min, r_max+1)) < len(range(l_max, r_min+1)):
        sl = slice(l_max, r_min+1)
    elif prod(arr[l_min:r_max+1]) >= prod(arr[l_max:r_min+1]):
        sl = slice(l_min, r_max+1) 
    else:
        sl = slice(l_max, r_min+1)
    return prod(arr[sl])
```

than this:

```
from operator import mul
from functools import reduce

cmp = lambda a, b: (a > b) - (a < b)
prod = lambda iterable: reduce(mul, iterable, 1)

def prod_between_min_and_max(arr):
    l_min, r_max = arr.index(min(arr)), len(arr)-1 - arr[::-1].index(max(arr))
    l_max, r_min = arr.index(max(arr)), len(arr)-1 - arr[::-1].index(min(arr))
    sl = [
        [
            slice(l_max, r_min+1),
            slice(l_min, r_max+1)
        ][
            prod(arr[l_min:r_max+1]) >= prod(arr[l_max:r_min+1])
        ], 
        slice(l_min, r_max+1), 
        slice(l_max, r_min+1)
    ][
        cmp(len(range(l_min, r_max+1)), len(range(l_max, r_min+1)))
    ]
    return prod(arr[sl])
```

**Note**: The code works in both Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: I would argue that version two is neither more compact nor more readable.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, Maybe. I look at the code for so long so I can not see it

Comment: Is your code compliant with both python 2 and 3?

Comment: @dfhwze yes, it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slicing lists can be slow, as it performs a copy of the slice in memory, as such, you could write `prod` like:

```
def product(iterable, start, stop=None, step=None):
    if stop is None:
        stop = start
        start = 0
    elements = itertools.islice(iterable, start, stop, step)
    return functools.reduce(operator.mul, elements, 1)
```

You should also define an [`rindex`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6890255/5069029) function that find an element starting from the end of a sequence:

```
def rindex(sequence, value):
    reverse_enumerate = zip(range(len(sequence) - 1, -1, -1), reversed(sequence))
    return next(i for i, v in reverse_enumerate if v == value)
```

Using these, you can write your main function:

```
def product_between_min_and_max(sequence):
    min_element = min(sequence)
    max_element = max(sequence)

    l_min = sequence.index(min_element)
    l_max = sequence.index(max_element)
    r_max = rindex(sequence, max_element)
    r_min = rindex(sequence, min_element)

    if r_max - l_min > r_min - l_max or (r_max - l_min == r_min - l_max
            and product(sequence, l_min, r_max + 1) >= product(sequence, l_max, r_min + 1)):
        sl = (l_min, r_max)
    else:
        sl = (l_max, r_min)
    return product(sequence, sl[0], sl[1] + 1)
```

You can also simplify ranges by adding 1 at both `r_max` and `r_min` since it won't change the result of the tests:

```
def product_between_min_and_max(sequence):
    min_element = min(sequence)
    max_element = max(sequence)

    l_min = sequence.index(min_element)
    l_max = sequence.index(max_element)
    # Add one to simplify writing the slices
    # Doesn't change (in)equality testings to have +1 on both sides
    r_max = rindex(sequence, max_element) + 1
    r_min = rindex(sequence, min_element) + 1

    if r_max - l_min > r_min - l_max or (r_max - l_min == r_min - l_max
            and product(sequence, l_min, r_max) >= product(sequence, l_max, r_min)):
        sl = l_min, r_max
    else:
        sl = l_max, r_min
    return product(sequence, *sl)
```

Answer (score 4):

The second example is terrible, don't use it.

---

You assign `sl` to either `(l_min, r_max)` or `(l_max, r_min)`, and so you just need to change your `if`s to become one `if` and an `else`.

First off `len(range(l_min, r_max+1))` is the same as `r_max+1 - l_min`, and there's no need for the `+1` if both sides have it. So your first `if` could become: `r_max - l_min > r_min - l_max`.

To merge the first and third, you should check it's the first, or explicitly check it's not the second and is the third. And so you can get:

```
def prod_between_min_and_max(arr):
    l_min = arr.index(min(arr))
    l_max = arr.index(max(arr))
    r_max = len(arr)-1 - arr[::-1].index(max(arr))
    r_min = len(arr)-1 - arr[::-1].index(min(arr))
    if (r_max - l_min > r_min - l_max
      or (r_max - l_min == r_min - l_max
          and prod(arr[l_min:r_max+1]) >= prod(arr[l_max:r_min+1]))):
        sl = (l_min, r_max)
    else:
        sl = (l_max, r_min)
    return prod(arr[slice(sl[0], sl[1]+1)])
```

This reminds me of `FizzBuzz`, as there doesn't seem to be a 'nice' solution.